# TCA how to set image description or alternative required

Tags: typo3

Is there a possibility to set the description of assets required?

The number of files i can detedermine with:

```
'assets' =>

              [
                'config' => [
                    'minitems' => 1,
                    'maxitems' => 1,
                ],
            ],
```

but how to set the description, title or alternative of the image required?

Answer (score 1):

The assets field is an inline relation to "sys_file_reference". As you overrode the assets configuration of pages / tt_content you can also change the field configuration of sys_file_reference adding `'eval' => 'required'` to those fields configuration. The problem: Those fields got a checkbox about the heredity of description, title and so on from the filelist. So maybe the field is filled in the meta-data in the filellist but not in the inline element which caused an validation error for me in TYPO3 6 LTS. Maybe TYPO3 7 or 8 LTS can handle "required" for those field already but I don't have time to test it right now.

Answer (score 1):

As these fields belongs to `sys_file_reference`, the only way is to marking all `sys_file_reference`s this fields as required:

`$GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_file_reference']['columns']['description']['config']['eval'] = 'required';`